# How to show cyrillic messages in UIAlertView in apportable

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, apportable

When I try to show cyrillic chars or specific chars like "★" in UIAlertView* instead of messages it's show some random chars (maybe 1, maybe 10..).

Examples:

```
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Тест тема (cyr)"
                             message:@"Message with char ★"
                            delegate:self
                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Ок (cyr)"
                   otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
```

In result I have:

```
Title:       " 5 A B
Message:     M
Button:      :
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106135/asihttprequest-and-cyrillic-letters to see if it helps.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into my iOS app and the alert shows the title and message exactly as it should.

Comment: @BlueTomato I'm not use HTTP request. I just show alert-view via apportable SDK

Comment: @rmaddy in iOS of cause it's work. Did you try apportable SDK?

Comment: Whether or not you are making an http request is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with non-ASCII characters in strings that is planned to be fixed in the Apportable platform in the next few months. In the meantime, a workaround is:

```
[[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"Тест тема (cyr)"]
                             message:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"Message with char ★"]
                            delegate:self
                   cancelButtonTitle:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"Ок (cyr)"]
                   otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
```